# How to run multiple Python scripts from command line?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have ten python scripts in the same directory. How to run all of these from command line, that it will work in background?

I use SSH terminal to connect to server CentOS and run Python script as:

```
python index.py
```

But when I close client terminal SSH, proccess is died

Comment: can they run in parallel or do some need to run sequentially? (note there are many ways to accomplish this no matter what..)

Comment: Maybe consider `nohup` or `screen`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `&` command to make things run in the background, and `nohup` so it continues on logout, such as

```
nohup python index.py &
```

If you want to run multiple things this way, it's probably easiest to just make a script to start them all (with a shell of your choice):

```
#!/bin/bash
nohup python index1.py &
nohup python index2.py &
...
```

Comment: Need I install `nohup` as module in Cent OS 7.2?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you don't need to interact with the scripts once they are started (and don't need any stdout printing) this could be pretty easily automated with another python script using the subprocess module:

```
for script in listofscripts:
    #use subprocess.run() for python 3.x (this blocks until each script terminates)
    subprocess.call(["python", script], *args) #use popen if you want non - blocking
```

*args is a link (it's coloring got overwritten by code highliting

also of note: stdout / stderr printing is possible, just more work..